# Generate .jpg by using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to generate a .jpg file by using vb.net desktop application. 
Example: the program will paint a simple rectangle with grey color, and produce as a physical image file (.jpg)

Any sample coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can directly save a Bitmap object as a jpg.

```
Dim bm As Bitmap

bm.Save("test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to view this tutorial: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_drawing_framework.html